# Writing plugin to develop composer attribute tables?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, print-composer

I have no experience of plugin development, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to write a plugin that solved the issue of multi-line tables in print composer http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10273

I now have several GIS projects in QGIS, having found this software only a few months ago, after having several teething troubles answered in this site, the only thing preventing me from just printing up my projects is the lack of multi-line support in print composer tables. I'm therefore looking at every possibility for solving this problem, including programming it myself, but I don't want to start the process if it's not even possible.

Does anyone know if such a plugin is possible, or that just not the sort of thing that plugins can do?

It seems such a small thing.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible unfortunately -- composer is quite limited in terms of what plugins can modify. Adding this support would take some non-trivial changes to QGIS itself.